# Javascript error appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, methods

Im trying to assign a delete button to all my li elements and I`m using the appenChild() method but it gives me an error: "appendChild is not a function". I cant understand why this is happening.

This is my code:

```
function createTrashes() {
    //button creation with icon
    var createButton = document.createElement("button");
    createButton.classList.add("trashButtons");
    //create icon
    var icon = document.createElement("i");
    icon.classList.add("fa", "fa-trash");
    //asignt icon to button
    createButton.appendChild(icon);
    //append button to all list elements
    var list = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    list.appendChild(createButton);
}

createTrashes();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` which does not have a `appendChild` function. You should be able to iterate over each `Node` in the list and call the `appendChild` function.
Try something like this:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
{
  let item = list[i];
  item.appendChild(createButton);
}
```

I found this information on the MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: FYI, this is not going to work either. There will only be one button

Comment: Good point he may have to create a button for each node in the list while iterating over the list